# Add highchart graph to mpdf()

Tags: php, highcharts, mpdf

How to add high chart graph to mpdf() as I was tried to add graph to mpdf(). If any  one knows about how to add graph to mpdf library.

Comment: You'll need to add it as an image, not as a highcharts (js) graph.... PDF doesn't understand js

Comment: Hi @Ali Abdullah, you can edit with your code inform what you have tried  and it make easy to read and help you

Comment: @Mark baker is it possible to get an image of hichart graph runtime and add it to the mpdf....

Comment: [4 different ways to save a Highcharts chart as a PNG (with and without a server)](https://gist.github.com/philfreo/0a4d899de4257e08a000)

Answer (score 0):

"mPDF" does not support this directly.

There are alternative approaches where you can render the charts in a browser, Highchart's server or a headless web browser.